# How to fix TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'?

Tags: python

I have this codes

```
config.plugins.FreeServer.Updattimeiptv = ConfigIP(default=[0, 0, 0, 0], auto_jump=True)

        def __init__(self):
            config.plugins.FreeServer.Updattimeiptv.value = self.Verif_1(config.plugins.FreeServer.Updattimeiptv.value)

        def Verif_1(self, Valist):
            if int(Valist[0]) < 10:
                if int(Valist[1]) < 10:
                    Valist = ['0' + str(Valist[0]), '0' + str(Valist[1])]
                else:
                    Valist = ['0' + str(Valist[0]), int(Valist[1])]
            elif int(Valist[1]) < 10:
                Valist = [int(Valist[0]), '0' + str(Valist[1])]
            else:
                Valist = [int(Valist[0]), int(Valist[1])]
            return Valist
```

If I want to typing new numbers I have got error

```
2021-11-02 13:00:48+0300 [-]   File "/usr/lib/enigma2/python/Components/config.py", line 949, in validate
2021-11-02 13:00:48+0300 [-]     if self._value[num] < self.limits[num][0]:
2021-11-02 13:00:48+0300 [-] TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

The file of (/usr/lib/enigma2/python/Components/config.py) it is stander file I can not change it from source.
https://github.com/openatv/enigma2/blob/7.0/lib/python/Components/config.py#L949
The issue not from config.py . It is from my codes that in above.

Comment: It looks very suspicious that `Valist` is sometimes a list of two integers, sometimes a list of two strings, and sometimes a list with one string and one integer. I would expect the library code to be expecting elements of the same type, and probably just one specific type.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tells you that you can't compare a `string` and an `integer`. One of them is string, so try

```
int(self._value[num])
```

or

```
int(self.limits[num][0])
```

One of them should work

Comment: As I said I can not change source file (config.py) . I need to fix my code only.